# editing .bashrc file to display name current date and time

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, display, vmware-workstation

how can I get my terminal to display
MSU-[current date]-[current time]>
using the bashrc?
I want it to display my name the current date and the current time in the terminal.
I have added a new PS1 line with that code in the gedit ~/.bashrc file but it isn't working. This is in the VMWARE workstation pro using ubuntu

Comment: What did you set your PS1 to? What does  `it isn't working` mean? Error message, incorrect output?

Comment: Enjoy! [prompt-generator](https://scriptim.github.io/bash-prompt-generator/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. [bashrcgenerator](https://bashrcgenerator.com/) to generate PS1 with your wish elements, e.g. name, date, current folder etc.

Then paste it in to your `.bashrc` and source it:

```bash
source .bashrc
```

E.g.:

```bash
PS1="\u-[\d]-[\t]>\[$(tput sgr0)\]"

# which produces the look as follows:
# username-[Mon Feb 22]-[14:23:52]>
```

Comment: thank you so much, how do I edit my username? sorry for the questions I am brand new.

Comment: \u in PS1 example I have given above will automatically get your username. So copy the line with PS1 and paste it in the end of your .bashrc and source it as shown above. If you think the answer was helpful please consider accepting and voting up the answer.